# C# How to get value from child class

Tags: c#

I am new in C#, in class B I set value to variable "onlyClassA" to "6" and I have to have the same value "6" in A's variable "onlyClassA" aswell. But my output value is "0".

```
A classA = new A();
B classB = new B(6);
Console.WriteLine("B value: " + classB.onlyClassA);
C classC = new C();
classC.WriteValues(classA);

class A : IA
{ 
    public int onlyClassA { get; set; } //this value has to be "6", but my console writes "0"

    public A()
    { }
    public A(int number)
    {
        onlyClassA = number;
    }   
}
class B : A
{
    public B(int number)
    { 
       onlyClassA = number;  
    }
}
class C
{
    public void WriteValues (IA write)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A value: " + write.onlyClassA);
    }
}
interface IA
{
    int onlyClassA { get; }
}

/*OUTPUT: 
B value: 6
A value: 0
But has to be:
B value: 6
A value: 6
*/
```

Thank you.

Comment: The `classA` variable refers to a **different object instance** than `classB`. That's what `new` means. You never set the value of that instance.

Comment: When you do "new A()" that instance has 0 in onlyClassA property. Later you use classC to write the onlyClassA property of classA, which is 0. Each object (A, B and C) has their own onlyClassA property.

Comment: The child class `B` really isn't relevant to what's going on here.  You'd observe the same thing with `A classA1 = new A(); A classA2 = new A(6);`.  They're separate instances with separate storage for their `onlyClassA` instance field.

Answer (score 0):

So, in initialization of `class A` you not provide parameter for `onlyClassA` field, and in constructor, your code didn't set field value of `onlyClassA`.

if you rewrite it to this, it will be value `6` in `classA` variable:

```
A classA = new A(6); // <- add initializer param
B classB = new B(6);
```

But in idea, its wrong, that you implement interface with `onlyClassA` field with `class B`, because your "parent tree" is `interface` -> `class` -> `subclass` and children have all fields and not-private methods of fathers. Interface, its a contract for realization class.